# ¿Cómo asignar la respuesta de una promesa a un array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo una promesa que obtiene datos de firebase, la cual va llenando en un array de strings los datos solicitados, ese mismo array es el que retorno en la promesa para poder utilizarlo.

Mi promesa es la siguiente:

```
listarEventos( eventos: string[] ) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    let nombres: string[] = [];
    eventos.forEach( (evento) => {
      this.db.collection('eventos').doc(evento).ref.get().then( (resp) => {
        if ( resp.exists ) {
          let a = resp.data().nombre; // <--- Este dato es de tipo STRING
          nombres.push(a);
        }
      }).catch( (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
    resolve(nombres);
  });
}
```

Todo funciona bien, pero al momento de querer utilizar este método me aparece el siguiente error:

```
error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'
```

Lo utilizo de la siguiente manera:

```
eventos: string[] = [];

this._eS.listarEventos(this.user.eventos).then( (resp) => {
  this.eventos = resp;
}).catch();
```

Aquí declaro un arreglo de string vacío, y al mandar a llamar el método de la promesa y obtener la respuesta me tira el error.

Comment: Qué dice si logueas el valor de `resp` a la consola? Me parece que el bucle con que intentas llenar `nombres` en la práctica no hace nada, porque estás iterando en forma síncrona y la promesa se resuelve con un array vacío, lo que no me explico es que se resuelva con un objeto `{}`.

Comment: Las promesas en Typescript tienen un tipo genérico que es el tipo de retorno de la promesa. ¿Has probado a devolver new Promise<string[]>((resolve, reject) ... ?

Comment: Muchas gracias, @RobertoPintosLópez . Esto es justo lo que necesitaba.